# Break the connection of wire with components:Segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, emgucv, aforge, accord.net

I want to remove the connecting points of wire with the components, The main purpose of doing this is to segment the image and detect only the resistor capacitor etc signs

What i have done is : erosion , dilation , etc

since the size of wire and component is nearly same so erosion dilation will not work

can anyone tell me how can i remove the point or segment the image

Thanks

[image]

Comment: "since the size of wire and component is nearly same so erosion dilation will not work ", huh, what do you mean?

Comment: I think you just need to detect the most dominant lines by using Hough Transform, and delete them. They should corresponds to circuit lines instead of elements. At least, it's worth a try.

Comment: it will also delete the other lines

Comment: @AnderBiguri I mean the size of wire and the size of components boundary is nearly same

Comment: Yes, but erode and dilate are not operations to get the width of lines. the logic erode dilate does not work because of the width is flawed. Also erode, dilation etc. Etc is not a function...

Comment: Use a skeleton algorithm creating lines of exactly 1 px thickness. Characterize every wire-colored pixel as "line" if it has exactly two 8-ring-neighbors and as a "junction" otherwise. Build a graph representation w/ nodes representing junctions and edges between them iff they are connected by a direct, junction-free path in the skeleton. Label each edge with a curvature approximation of the represented skeleton segment, e.g. the number of 90°-direction changes from pixel to a neighborpixel per length in pixels. Delete the edges/segments with the highest labels - the components remain. Done ;)

Comment: Could you add an full sized test image? Good idea @Thomas, but the resistor and coil -junctions have only two neighbours just as the lines do.

Comment: @Tapio You are right with the resistor, but the coil has a lot of crossings... with a little margin this might work as well. The resistor might be identified via corners PER LENGTH... but this is speculative.